# ¿Cómo se suman horas a una datos de fecha y hora?

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber si existe una función que permita sumar horas a una fecha por ejemplo:
La siguiente función devuelve la hora actual en Java:

```
private String getFechal(){
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd kk:mm:ss");
    String fecha = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
    return fecha;
}
```

devuelve un valor como 20/02/09 14:26:32
y Quiero sumar 6 horas a esa fecha pero que respete las reglas de una fecha, como las horas deben ser con un valor máximo de 24 horas, los días deben ser conforme al mes, y así sucesivamente

O si existe alguna manera de conocer la hora UTC+6 y TZBiasInMin o DSTBiasInMin

Comment: Obtén la marca de tiempo y súmale tantos milisegundos hay en 6 horas: `Date fecha2 = new Date(date.getTime()*6*60*60*1000);`

Comment: y sabes como calcular TZBiasInMin o DSTBiasInMin ?

Comment: Revisa las clases `GregorianCalendar`, `TimeZone` y `ZonedDateTime`.